# Samsung Tab 2 7.0 model GT P3113

Tags: battery

Recently I bought a replacement battery off trusted internet supplier, came with kit to remove back, and a short video to advise and old guy how to do it. All went well until I plugged in to charge up, the unit beeped loud, and flashed a warning yellow triangle with exclamation mark,and written advisement that battery was to hot and charging paused. I complained to supplier battery was bad they sent new one, with same results, since then did a factory reset, still same power, volume button clear reset same result, then in desperation to narrow down cause took original battery and cut blue line to battery plugged in and it is charging perfectly, am now monitoring for unusual temps in battery case and will stop if it heats up abnormally...... so is there a resistor between usb plug exterior, and battery plug interior that may not now be functioning if so can it be replaced or repaired????? anyone heard of such a thing? Am old but not out of it lol any help appreciated

Comment: If its charging fine, I doubt it. I would still follow the procedure of being very careful.

Comment: yes interestingly enough it reached 100% and suspended charging just like always, thermal temp of battery cool to touch, shows battery in discharge mode when unplugged not sure where to look for problem causing original problem of charging paused battery to hot, when this problem when physically measure was untrue? thoughts anyone?

Comment: Maybe it was a Fail-safe that was trigger happy? Some form of 'Official battery' check? And cutting the blue cable fixed/disabled that? I can only guess.